# Refresh data without loading page php sql

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, sql

I have an HTML table and PHP for it to process and show in HTML table. It get's refreshed everytime page is loaded but I want to auto-refresh every 1 second. Heres  PHP:-

```
    $seql = "select price, sum(total), sum(aleft) from trade where status = 'active' and bm = '$bm' and m = '$market' and type = 'sell' group by price";
     $query100 = mysqli_query($conn, $seql);
```

And html table

```
  <div style='float: left;'>
<br><br>
<p style="padding-left:16px; font-size: 20px;">Amount(<?php echo $market; ?>) | Price(<?php echo $bm; ?>) &nbsp | Total(<?php echo $bm; ?>)</p>
<div class="panel-hello scrollbar" id="style-11">
    <div class="data-table">
        <table class="table table-hello table-bordered table-hover force-overflow" id="btcaddresses">
            <tbody style="border: 1px solid green; height: 300px; overflow-y: scroll;">
                <?php
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query100))
    {
        echo '<tr style="cursor: pointer; font-size: 15px;">
                <td>'.number_format($row['sum(aleft)'], 8).'</td>
                <td>'.number_format($row['price'], 8).'</td>
                <td>'.number_format($row['sum(total)'], 8).'</td>
            </tr>';
    }?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Help is appreciated .

Comment: google for javscript ajax

Comment: But I really don't  know much in js and neither and much time